# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduleWithFixedDelay and "urgent" execution

Tags: java

I have the following problem that the standard library doesn't solve well, and I'm wondering if anybody has seen another library out there than can do it so I don't need to hack together a custom solution.  I have a task that is currently scheduled on a thread pool using scheduleWithFixedDelay(), and I need to modify the code to handle requests for "urgent" execution of the task related to asynchronous events.  Thus, if the task is scheduled to occur with a delay of 5 minutes between executions, and an event occurs 2 minutes after the last completed execution, I would like to execute the task immediately and then have it wait for 5 minutes after the completion of the urgent execution before it runs again.  Right now the best solution that I can come up with is to have the event handler call cancel() on the ScheduledFuture object returned by scheduleWithFixedDelay() and execute the task immediately, and then set a flag in the task to tell it to reschedule itself with the same delay parameters.  Is this functionality available already and I'm just missing something in the documentation?

Comment: The solution outlined sounds pretty good. Rather than having the urgent task re-add the scheduled task, it seems like the event handler would be in a good position to do this. It needs a handle to the new Future anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` there is a method `decorateTask` (well in fact there are two, for Runnable and Callable tasks) that you can override to store a reference to the task somewhere.

When you need urgent execution, you just call `run()` on that reference which makes it run and rescheduled with same delay.

A quick hack-up attempt:

```
public class UrgentScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extends
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {
    RunnableScheduledFuture scheduledTask;

    public UrgentScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize) {
        super(corePoolSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected  RunnableScheduledFuture decorateTask(Runnable runnable,
            RunnableScheduledFuture task) {
        scheduledTask = task;
        return super.decorateTask(runnable, task);
    }

    public void runUrgently() {
        this.scheduledTask.run();
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
public class UrgentExecutionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UrgentScheduledThreadPoolExecutor pool = new UrgentScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

        pool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ss"); 

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
            }
        }, 0, 2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        pool.runUrgently();
        pool.awaitTermination(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

and produces the following output:
06
08
10
***11***
13
15

Comment: This does not start the thread in the thread pool but rather the current thread. Would need a way of starting them in the background in the same way they would have been started otherwise..

Comment: @pandaadb Do you have any solution?

Comment: @AppiDevo i do indeed. Did you have a question to answer or should I add it here?

Comment: @pandaadb I don't have open question. You can post here as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @AppiDevo no problem. give me a few minutes, i am dealing with a different problem and writing up a test case too :)

Comment: @AppiDevo here we go

Answer (score 1):

as requested (soz, in a hurry) my EventBasedExecutor

Warning: **This currently only works for tasks that are scheduled in a periodic run. You can change the code to handle all the tasks, I so far haven't because I only have the periodically run task. I also run this in a signle-threaded threadpool (I only need one scheduled runner thread that is that runs in one dedicated thread all the time every X seconds)**

Here we go:

```
public class EventBasedExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implements EventBasedExecutorService {

    private List<RunnableScheduledFuture<?>> workers = new ArrayList<>();

    private int index;

    public EventBasedExecutor(int corePoolSize) {
        super(corePoolSize,  new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setDaemon(true).setNameFormat("message-sender-%d").build());
    }

    @Override
    protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Runnable runnable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
        if(!workers.contains(runnable)) {
            workers.add(task);
        }
        return super.decorateTask(runnable, task);
    }

    @Override
    public void executeEarly() {
        if(index >= workers.size()) {
            index = 0;
        }

        if(workers.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        RunnableScheduledFuture<?> runnableScheduledFuture = workers.get(index);
        index ++;
        execute(runnableScheduledFuture);
        System.out.println("Executing");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        EventBasedExecutor executor = new EventBasedExecutor(10);

        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // this will never run
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }, 5000, 5000, TimeUnit.HOURS);

        executor.executeEarly();

        System.out.println("Run after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTimeMillis));
    }

}
```

This will execute the task in the dedicated worker thread.

It will print:

```
Executing
hello
Run after: 39
```

Have fun hacking :)

artur

Answer (score 0):

There is also an obvious simple solution that does not require a new class.
The idea is to cancel the schedule on notification and re-schedule again:

```java
class MyClass {
  
    final static int DECISION_POINT = 1; //millisecond

    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private ScheduledFuture<?> periodicFuture;

    MyClass() {
        periodicFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::doWork, 1, 2,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    void doWorkAsap() {
        if (periodicFuture.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) > DECISION_POINT) {
            periodicFuture.cancel(true);
            periodicFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::doWork,
                0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }

    void doWork() { ... }

}
```

This only works well in certain situations where delay between tasks is reasonably big relative to overall system performance and overhead of creating new ScheduledFuture is acceptable. Also, special attention needs to be paid to the point of no return, called `DECISION_POINT` here, where it makes no more sense to schedule the new future, as natural order of things would be fast enough. For the tighter schedules than in the example above, use an approach similar to the pandaab one.